# How should we tag M.A.S.K?

Tags: discussion, tags

*I've accepted the option [mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-armored-strike-kommand) as that has currently the highest score (+14/-1). Adding a synonym for [mask-mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask-mobile-armored-strike-kommand) (so prefixed with `mask`) should improve the chances of the correct tag being found.*

---

Yesterday, this question was posted:

[Is there a canon source from the 1980s covering the death of Matt Tracker's brother from the MASK franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/256026/19561)

We didn't have a tag for the franchise, so I added [mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-armored-strike-kommand).

**Is this tag the best tag for this franchise?**

#### Considerations

The name of the franchise is *[M.A.S.K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.A.S.K.)*, which stands for Mobile Armored Strike Kommand. While not an actual backronym, since all characters wear helmets with special powers, it's likely that they came up with the acronym first, then made up something to fit it.

It consists of a toy line, an animated TV series that ran for two seasons (1985–1986), a short comics run, and three video games.

Currently, we don't have enough questions to warrant a subdivision for the different franchises. We went years without a single one. After the first one, we quickly received three other questions about the franchise (one of which was mine).

#### Suggestions

The following suggestions were made in chat:

##### [mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-armored-strike-kommand)

Current tag. Unambiguous, but not easily recognisable for people who only remember the acronym and not easily discoverable either.

##### [m-a-s-k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-a-s-k)

As close as we can get to the acronym. Pretty unambiguous, but still not easily discoverable.

##### [mask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask)

Very ambiguous, will need disambiguation in its usage guidance to differentiate between *M.A.S.K.*, *The Mask* (green-headed Jim Carrey), the DC villain, the general idea of masks, and possibly other characters or works with the same name. Easily discoverable, though.

##### [mask-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask-franchise)

May still need disambiguation to clarify *which* Mask franchise. Still easily discoverable.

##### [mask-1985](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask-1985)

We usually don't use tags with the year in it for an entire franchise, although in this case both the TV series and the toy line are from that same year. Still easily discoverable.

Comment: To be honest, when I read the title, I thought this was about the movie The Mask. I think the full text sounds like the best.

Comment: the tag [tag:the-mask] already exists, so there no need to worry about overlap there

Comment: @AncientSwordRage of course, but when typing `mask` and seeing both [tag:mask] and [tag:the-mask], the usage guidance of those tags should clarify what is what.

Comment: Oh of course, I hadn't properly read the whole sentence, and I assumed the issue was the possibility of the tag being claimed by other works, such as if the Jim Carrey film had claimed [tag:mask] instead of [tag:the-mask]

Comment: Just "Mask" makes me think of the Cher movie first.

Comment: How many questions and when was the last one that was tagged as being about M.A.S.K. ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### [mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-armored-strike-kommand)

Current tag. Unambiguous, but not easily recognised for people who only remember the acronym and not easily discoverable.

Comment: I'd vote for this, with the addendum that we make [tag:mask] a synonym until such a time we need it for another tag. That way typing *mask* will pop this up, and the other tags that match, and the user can pick between them.

Comment: My preference would be to have [tag:m-a-s-k] either as the primary with this as a synonym, or vice versa.

Comment: The issue with not involving [tag:mask], is that as you start typing in 'mask' when asking a question (which I'd bet is 99% of what people would do) afaik you aren't going to hit [tag:m-a-s-k] or [tag:mobile-armored-strike-kommand].

Comment: @AncientSwordRage We might want to make the synonym mask-something just so typing mask still brings it up but if you just put in mask meaning something else it won't auto-change it to this.

Comment: How about [tag:mask-mobile-armored-strike-kommand]? Perhaps as a synonym?

Answer (score 9):

### [m-a-s-k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-a-s-k)

As close as we can get to the acronym. Pretty unambiguous, but not easily discoverable unless the querent guesses how we turned the acronym into a tag.

Comment: The major problem here is that the dashes are not going to be typed by users and typing "mask" may not yield the tag.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest an option not mentioned: synonyms. Mods can create them and when you type in the term, they show up.

The primary tag really is best for the SE system as [mobile-armored-strike-kommand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-armored-strike-kommand). I propose adding these synonyms to it so you can find it if trying to tag "mask" (i.e. [mask-tv]). Not ideal, but we have some tags like that already (i.e. [powerless-tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerless-tv))

Comment: The Mask also had an animated TV series

Comment: @SpacePhoenix True, but it's titled **The** Mask (and is tagged [the-mask] as well). Remember that the synonym only allows it to show up when people type "mask". The actual tag should help steer people to the correct one to use.

Answer (score -1):

### [mask-1985](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask-1985)

We usually don't use tags with the year in it for an entire franchise, although in this case both the TV series and the toy line are from that same year.

Easily discoverable.

Answer (score -2):

What about:

"The-Mask(Jim-Carrey-Movie)"

MASK(Mobile-Armored-Strike-Kommand)

The-Mask(Cartoon-TV-series)

A little long winded but it makes it clear which franchise a question will be about. I don't recall ever seeing any questions about The Mask TV series (the one based on the Jim Carrey film)

Comment: That's not really possible within the limitations of the tag system.

Comment: @SQB what are the limits of the tag system?

Comment: Parentheses aren't available.

Comment: What about replacing the ( with a # and removing the ) at the end?

Answer (score -3):

### [mask-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask-franchise)

May still need disambiguation to clarify *which* Mask franchise. Easily discoverable.

Answer (score -4):

### [mask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mask)

Very ambiguous, will need disambiguation in its usage guidance to differentiate between *M.A.S.K.*, *The Mask* (green-headed Jim Carrey), the DC villain, the general idea of masks, and possibly other characters or works with the same name.

Easily discoverable, though.